# Two code bases with the same code but one is generating an overload resolution compilation error and the other isn't

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017, vulkan, overload-resolution

I'm following *Jonno Robson's* source code for a Vulkan App that can be found on github here: [Vulkan-Terrain-Generator](https://github.com/JonnoRobson/Vulkan-Terrain-Generator). I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on a Window's 7 64bit machine.

I have my own solution and project where everything has been typed by hand, but I also have a downloaded clone to their project so that I can use it side by side in my attempt to learn and better understand the Vulkan API.

In the **Renderer** class's `initPipelines()` function we are setting up all of the different pipelines for the rendered scene. In the section where we are setting up the **TerrainRenderingPipeline** there is a call to `addTextureArray()` that the inherited class invokes from its base class member. The **TerrainRenderingPipeline** class inherits from the **Pipeline** base class.

This is how it is being called in the **Render** class's `initPipelines()` method:

```
terrain_rendering_pipeline_->addTextureArray(VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT, 3, terrain_generator_->getHeightmaps());
```

In my solution; this fails to compile and Visual Studio is generating a `C2664` error complaining about overload resolution. However; when I compile and build Jonno's project there are no issues.

---

These are the function declarations for the `addTextureArray(...)` functions
that are found in `pipeline.h`:

```
void addTextureArray(VkShaderStageFlags stage_flags, uint32_t binding_location, std::vector<Texture*>& textures);
void addTextureArray(VkShaderStageFlags stage_flags, uint32_t binding_location, std::vector<VkImageView>& textures);
```

and these are the definitions that are found in `pipeline.cpp`

```
void VulkanPipeline::addTextureArray(VkShaderStageFlags stage_flags, uint32_t binding_location, std::vector<Texture*>& textures) {
    Descriptor texture_descriptor = {};

    // setup image info
    for (Texture* texture : textures) {
        VkDescriptorImageInfo image_info = {};
        image_info.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
        image_info.imageView = texture->getImageView();
        image_info.sampler = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
        texture_descriptor.image_infos.push_back(image_info);
    }

    // setup descriptor layout info
    texture_descriptor.layout_binding.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_SAMPLED_IMAGE;
    texture_descriptor.layout_binding.descriptorCount = texture_descriptor.image_infos.size();
    texture_descriptor.layout_binding.binding = binding_location;
    texture_descriptor.layout_binding.stageFlags = stage_flags;
    texture_descriptor.layout_binding.pImmutableSamplers = nullptr;

    descriptor_infos_.push_back(texture_descriptor);
}

void VulkanPipeline::addTextureArray(VkShaderStageFlags stage_flags, uint32_t binding_location, std::vector<VkImageView>& textures) {
    Descriptor texture_descriptor = {};

    // setup image info
    for (VkImageView texture : textures) {
        VkDescriptorImageInfo image_info = {};
        image_info.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
        image_info.imageView = texture;
        image_info.sampler = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
        texture_descriptor.image_infos.push_back(image_info);
    }

    // setup descriptor layout info
    texture_descriptor.layout_binding.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_SAMPLED_IMAGE;
    texture_descriptor.layout_binding.descriptorCount = texture_descriptor.image_infos.size();
    texture_descriptor.layout_binding.binding = binding_location;
    texture_descriptor.layout_binding.stageFlags = stage_flags;
    texture_descriptor.layout_binding.pImmutableSamplers = nullptr;

    descriptor_infos_.push_back(texture_descriptor);
}
```

Finally for the **TerrainGenerator** class's `getHeightmaps()` function that returns a `std::vector<VkImageView>` is found in `terrain_generator.h`:

```
inline std::vector<VkImageView> getHeightmaps() { return heightmap_image_views_; }
```

I believe this is all of the relevant code that involves this issue.

---

Here is the generated Visual Studio Compiler Error:

```
1>c:\users\skilz99\source\repos\vulkan terrain generator\vulkan terrain generator\renderer.cpp(522): error C2664: 'void VulkanPipeline::addTextureArray(VkShaderStageFlags,uint32_t,std::vector<VkImageView,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)': cannot convert argument 3 from 'std::vector<VkImageView,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'std::vector<Texture *,std::allocator<_Ty>> &'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=VkImageView
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Ty=VkImageView
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Texture *
1>        ]
1>c:\users\skilz99\source\repos\vulkan terrain generator\vulkan terrain generator\renderer.cpp(545): warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'double' to 'T'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=float
1>        ]
```

---

What I don't understand is why is it failing to compile in my project-solution, but not in his... Any kind of tips or suggestions would be very helpful. If you need anymore information about the code please don't hesitate to ask. I tried to post the minimal possible amount of code as this is a decent size project.

Comment: Please include the actual error you get (in full and complete of course).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay no problem I can add it.

Comment: I've tripled check my code versus their code and couldn't find any discrepancies between the two that pertains to this compiler error. I've been shaking my head for a couple of days on this now and don't understand why it's being generated in my code base, but not Jonno's...

Comment: Where does it say anything about overload resolution?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay I updated the post with the added compiler error.

Comment: @melpomene The compiler error says it can not convert from one object to another; it's not resolving the overloaded method.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `getHeightmaps` function in the call to `addTextureArray`, the object it returns is a *temporary* object. Temporary objects can't be bound to non-const references. And the `addTextureArray` take a non-const reference argument for the vector.

Either the `addTextureArray` function have to be modified to accept a `const` reference as the third argument:

```
void addTextureArray(VkShaderStageFlags, uint32_t, std::vector<Texture*> const&);
void addTextureArray(VkShaderStageFlags, uint32_t, std::vector<VkImageView> const&);
```

**Or** you have to modify the `getHeightmaps` function to return a reference:

```
inline std::vector<VkImageView>& getHeightmaps() { return heightmap_image_views_; }
```

Comment: @FrancisCugler Different build flags? Or something else that differs from your build. It's impossible to tell really.

Comment: I've check through their solutions project settings and I didn't see anything different than the basic defaults. The only differences are I had to change the paths to link in the external libraries.

Comment: I think I found out the culprit. I double checked the project's property settings and under C/C++->Language->Conformance mode; by default in my project it was set to yes(/permissive) and in their project it was set to no... I changed that in my project and it now compiles. It was something that I had previously overlooked. Should I append this to my question or should I add my own answer since changing this compiler flag resolved my issue?

Comment: @FrancisCugler Visual C++ have an extension to the C++ language that allows it to bind temporary objects to non-constant references. By enabling strict conformance to C++ this extension is disabled. But it doesn't make the code (as shown in your question) correct, it's still not "proper" C++. You should probably report it as a bug to the project.

Comment: You're probably right; and this is why I was shaking my head for 2 days...

Comment: Well his project when I build and run it; it does work and I can move around the generated 3D Scene with the procedural generated Terrain. I'm just trying to get my project to reflect theirs and to work first. Then I'll go from there to try to improve some features, fix bugs, and improve efficiency while trying to conform to modern C++ best practices. It's just a way for me to learn the Vulkan API.

Comment: My original choice before I asked this question was your 2nd solution to the problem. I had actually done that. But because I'm in the debugging mode trying to get my solution to render the scene; I ended up reverting back because I was trying to match my code with his to get mine to work first. My solution is building and the application is running but it's not rendering the scene. It could be in one of the dozens of class's, it could be in one of the handful of shaders. Yeah; I have my work cut out for me.

Answer (score 0):

After taking `Some programmer dude`'s answer into consideration which would be the appropriate way to fix such an issue in conformance to modern C++ best practices. It was still making me wonder why the code would compile under Jonno's solution and not mine. Then `Some programmer dude` had mentioned in a comment,

> Different build flags? Or something else that differs from your build. It's impossible to tell really.

So I went back and check the project settings and to my surprise there was one single compiler flag that I had over looked that was different.

In my solution by default when originally creating it under:

- Configuration Properties

  - C/C++

    - Language -> Conformance mode

mine was set to `Yes (/permissive-)` by default and under Jonno's project his was set to no.

Once I changed this in my project's properties, it now compiles.